# How can I select all the instances in which the values of Columns A & B in Sheet 1 are exactly equal to Columns A & B of Sheet 2?

Tags: database, excel, vba, xlsx, xls

This one is quite specific, but basically I've been given two data dumps (in .xls format): one from an old system and one from the new system. There are many more rows in the new system's dump, but I would like to remove the rows that are already found in the old system's dump.

Each sheet contains about 10 columns, but only 2 of those columns will actually have potentially matching values.

**So my question can be summarised as: How can I select all the instances in which the values of Columns A & B in Sheet 1 (old dump) are exactly equal to Columns A & B of Sheet 2 (new dump)?**

Comment: Show us your vba script, so that we might help you in a better way. Personally I'll convert the xls file into csv, parse it with Python or javascript, then apply list-comprehension technique. But I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: That might be what I want. I'm very new to this, learning as I go. I don't have a VBA script yet, just wondering how to start approaching this issue.

Comment: Are they both in the same file?

Comment: Yes, as two separate sheets in an .xlsx document. Although I also have them as separate files.

Comment: There are many values repeated in column A, and many repeated in column B. However, every combination of A&B is unique. This is the common ground between the two data sets and what I'm trying to target with rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a helper column in sheet 1 and in sheet 2. And put a formula in that concatenates column A & column B e.g.

```
=A1&B1
```

In the images below Column K has the formula in that combines column A & column B values. Column L is for illustrative purposes and shows you what the formula contained in column K is.

In the old sheet:

[image: Sheet1: Old data dump]

In sheet2 you have both the helper column K and an additional formula in column L as shown in image below. Column M in this case is showing you the formula in column L:

[image: Sheet2: New data dump]

Column L in this has the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(K2,Old!K:K,0)),"Keep","Delete")
```

The inner part looks to see if column K value in the new data dump can be found in column K of the old data dump i.e. is there a match for both column A and B values.

```
MATCH(K2,Old!K:K,0) 'This would be MATCH(K2,Sheet1!K:K,0) in your case
```

If no match is found i.e. a particular column A and B combination is found in the new but not in the old, the MATCH formula will return `#N/A`.

The outer part of the column L formula tests for this error with `ISNA()`
which returns True for an error and False otherwise.

Putting this inside of the `IF()` statement in column L (in the sheet2) you have a formula that says, if match found "Delete",if not found "Keep".

You can then filter on column L for entries that say "Delete" and then delete them.

[image: Ctrl & Shift & L to filter results on rows to delete]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much. Although for some reason it won't show "Keep" & "Delete", simply TRUE or FALSE. That still works fine though, thank you.

Comment: You would need to ensure you have the formula =IF(ISNA(MATCH(K2,Old!K:K,0)),"Keep","Delete")

Comment: Got it to display nicely, really appreciate it QHarr. Been trying to figure this out for a while; the 'helper' column is what I wasn't considering properly. Thanks for being so detailed.